# How can I compute similarity/distance between two multidimensional matrices?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, computational-mathematics, python

I have two matrices with numeric and nominal data types (categories). Both matrices are multidimensional and don't have the same number of elements (lines).

**Examples:**

Matrix 1:
[[2,"Peru",29,"Green"]
[3,"USA",28,"Blue"]
[2,"Spain",20,"Black"]]

Matrix 2:
[[3,"USA",28,"Blue"]
[2,"Spain",20,"Black"]]

---

How can I compute the similarity between these two matrices?

I assume that two matrices are similar if they have similar number of lines and I if they have similar lines (numeric values are close and categorical values are the same).

Comment: What does similarity mean mathematically ?

Comment: @Digitalis For me means distance. Example: 28 is closer to 29 than 28 to 20